# Watch for changes in an npm link package being built with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, lerna, monorepo

I have the following directory structure:

```
application
          |
          |__ component-library
             |
             |__src
          |
          |__ app
             |
             |__src
```

I have used [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to link `component-library` in `app`.

At the minute I am linking to the compiled output of the `component-library`.

I want to somehow listen for changes in the component library folder which will cause a recompilation.

Would I need to use gulp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use yarn workspaces instead of lerna, but its essentially the same thing (`--hoist` option from lerna by default).

I'm going to assume that you are starting webpack from the root of `application` with the `watch` option set to `true` (or are using `webpack-dev-server`) during development, that you have a [prepare script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#deprecation-note) setup in `component-library`'s package.json for publishing, and that `app` lists modules from `component-library` as dependencies in its package.json (i.e. does not use a relative path during import/require of modules from `component-library`).

> I want to somehow listen for changes in the component library folder
>   which will cause a recompilation.
>
> Would I need to use gulp?

You would need some utility to watch for file changes in `component-library`, not necessarily gulp, but you could. When a file from `component-library` changes you would want to rerun the `prepare` script so that it republishes the package, whereupon `webpack` would notice a module in its dependency graph changed and would rebuild the root `application` (possibly kicking of a browser reload depending on your development setup). Note, it is not sufficient to simply watch files in `component-library` without rebuilding/publishing because webpack has the build of `component-library` in its dependency graph, not the development source code.

If you wanted to use gulp a watch task might look something like this:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

gulp.watch('path/to/component-library/src/*.js', () => {
    let prepare = spawn('yarn', ['run', 'prepare'], {
        cwd: 'path/to/component-library',
        stdio: 'inherit'
    });

    prepare.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            prepare.emit('end');
        }
    });

    // gulp 4 allows returning a child process to signal async completion
    return prepare;
});
```

Due to the lerna symlinks webpack's `watch` option can see a module changed and will rebuild the root `application`.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.  Do you supply sourcemaps from the component-library build?

Comment: You can if you want to be friendly to the consumers of component-library, although you should make them external (i.e. not inline).  Technically component-library is a dependency that should work without errors so sourcemaps wouldn't be needed, but since its a dependency within your own project providing sourcemaps in the published build would help with its own development.